# Drupal get a value of a select list not a keys?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, field

How can I get all options for a fields?

For example, There is a field with 3 options in allowed values, like option1, option2, option3.Is there any function which receive the field name and returns selected values not a keys ?

With this just return key of selected opinion

```
  print ($node->field_opinion['und'][0]['value'])
```

Comment: Did you try something like print_r($node->field_option) to see if some field contains those values?

Comment: Yes Result : Array
(
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

)

Comment: Yes, but beside that [und][0][value]...is there something else useful?

Comment: @MilanG No "1" just the field keys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using list_allowed_values function :

```html
$key = $node->field_opinion['und'][0]['value'];
$options = list_allowed_values('field_opinion');
$label = $options[$key];
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for my use case, I had to do the following:

```
$key = // db_select('node'...
$field_definition = field_info_field('field_name');
$options = list_allowed_values(field_definition, 'node');
$label = $options[$key];
```